# Using kubernetes-dashboard with outh2-proxy and keycloak (and EKS) - unauthorized

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to use oauth-proxy to provide authentication on the kubernetes dashboard using keycloak in EKS.

I have managed to get to a point where oauth-proxy will forward the authorization header to the dashboard, however I am getting 'unauthorized' in the dashboard.

From what I can gather, the dashboard is expecting a field in the header with the `id_token` however the version of keycloak I am using does not seem to provide it... It is not clear to me if this is an issue with the way I have configured keycloak or an issue with something else.

Both oauth-proxy and kubernetes dashboard are deployed using helm with the following config:

```yaml
kubernetes-dashboard:
  app:
    ingress:
      enabled: true 
      ingressClassName: nginx
      issuer:
        name: letsencrypt
        scope: cluster
      paths:
        web: /
        api: /api
      annotations: 
        external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kubernetes-dashboard.example.com
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "64k"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: 'https://kubernetes-dashboard.example.com/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri'
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: 'https://kubernetes-dashboard.example.com/oauth2/auth'
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "Authorization"
      hosts:
        - kubernetes-dashboard.example.com

  nginx:
    enabled: false

  cert-manager:
    enabled: false
    installCRDs: false
  
  metrics-server:
    enabled: false

oauth2-proxy: 
  config:
    existingSecret: "kubernetes-dashboard-oidc-secret"
    configFile: | 
      provider="keycloak-oidc"
      provider_display_name="Keycloak"
      redirect_url="https://kubernetes-dashboard.example.com/oauth2/callback"

      email_domains = [ "*" ]
      oidc_issuer_url="https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm"
      scope = "openid email groups"
      upstreams = [ "https://kubernetes-dashboard.example.com" ]

      cookie_secure = true

      set_authorization_header = true

  metrics:
    enabled: false

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    path: /oauth2
    className: nginx
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "64k"
    hosts:
      - kubernetes-dashboard.example.com
    tls:
      - secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-tls
        hosts:
          - "kubernetes-dashboard.example.com"

  sessionStorage:
    type: redis
    redis:
      password: ""

  redis: 
    enabled: true 
    architecture: standalone
```

**Versions**

oauth2-proxy: Helm 6.16.1 (app 7.4.0)

kubernetes-dashboard: Helm 7.0.3 (app v3.0.0-alpha0)

Keycloak: 21.1.1

EKS Version: 1.26

**EKS OIDC Config**

[image: EKS OIDC Config]

**Keycloak Config**

[image: Keycloak Config]

I am using the same client in keycloak that I use for kubelogin using oidc (which does work).

**EKS Logs***

I believe these are the errors for the dashboard - but sadly they are not clear...
[image]

**jwt token**

So when I visit `https://kubernetes-dashboard.example.com/oauth2/callback` I can see the authorization header but it does not contain an `id_token`...

[image: jwt token]

When I get to the page - it logs in, however none of the resources are displayed... I am assuming that this is because the Authorization token is being passed and it does not contain the `id_token`, however nothing I have seemed to try appears to get it into the header... This would confirm why I am getting the errors in the API server...

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm curious, are you able to run kubectl commands against the cluster after you authenticate to Keycloak?

Comment: Hey @JeremyCowan - yes I can and that works fine... I have used this https://github.com/int128/kubelogin to do this, but I have a feeling that kubectl does an intermediate step to get the actual token.

Comment: I haven't seen this particular configuration before, i.e. using Keycloak to authenticate to the k8s dashboard, but I found an old blog post that may help, https://www.tigera.io/blog/single-sign-on-for-kubernetes-dashboard-experience/. Incidentally, you can view all the objects in a cluster from the EKS console. As an alternative the dashboard, you can use Octant, k9s, or Lens.

Comment: So there are a couple of blog posts out there that talk about it - I think as long as the token is in there, it should pass this through to the api and this is what it would use to pull through the details... Looking into it, it seems like this is an issue with the oauth2-proxy and that using the `alphaConfig` option I should be able to inject the token into the response - https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/843. So I will be honest I am not a massive fan of the EKS dashboard (and requires console access). Currently using k9s and will have a look through the links! Will update!

Comment: So it does look like the id_token is being used as a bearer token (or at least passed), although I am still getting 'unauthorized' everywhere...

Comment: are you able to login to the dashboard when you paste in the token that keycloak returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out I had made an error in the OIDC configuration for EKS... As I am now using a later version of keycloak, I needed to make sure the issuer url was:

`https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm`

and not

`https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/myrealm`

Frustratingly I had changed it everywhere else and not there... Everything now works as expected!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly supplying a token with the required groups claim, so users can authenticate. But the K8S API server needs to know what K8S resources to grant access to, so users are unauthorized.

So you next need to deploy RBAC resources for each group. For example, apply this YAML to grant read access to all K8S resources to members of the admins group:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admins-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ['*']
  resources: ['*']
  verbs: ['get', 'list', 'watch']
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admins-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: dashboard-admins-role
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: admins
```

**EDIT**

Also, these were my oauth2-proxy settings in case it helps:

```yaml
containers:
  - name: oauth2-proxy
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.4.0
    args:
    - --http-address=http://0.0.0.0:4180
    - --upstream=http://kubernetes-dashboard:9090
    - --provider=oidc
    - --provider-ca-file=/oidc-ca-cert/oidcroot.ca.pem
    - --skip-provider-button=true
    - --oidc-issuer-url=https://login.mycluster.com/oauth/v2/oauth-anonymous
    - --client-id=kubernetes_client
    - --client-secret=Password1
    - --redirect-url=https://dashboard.mycluster.com/oauth2/callback
    - --code-challenge-method=S256
    - --scope=openid email kubernetes_read
    - --oidc-groups-claim=kubernetes_groups
    - --cookie-secret=pYLu3xdlvkYNw_e-TsvRI3iXFsXlnYrQ_yYGhChY_80=
    - --cookie-secure=true
    - --email-domain=*
    - --insecure-oidc-allow-unverified-email=true
    - --pass-authorization-header=true
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply! Havent had a chance to revisit this! I did have these groups in place, but I have gone back to make sure the oidc-login is working and it isn't... looks like the configuration has changed... will get this working and then try again! Thanks for the steer!

Comment: @Gary Archer, I have the same issue but even I added the openid as scope and get the id_token I still getting unauthorized when login the the dashboard, apparently it is nos working with the groups or something 

I created the ClusterRole binging exactly like you mentioned and added my users to the groups **admins** 

in my id_token that claim groups exists with the value admins btw.

Comment: Maybe compare your settings to those I just added to my answer. Other than that it is a case of diagnosing logs for the dashboard, the proxy and the apuserver pods in the kube-systrem namespace.